# Data from database not same in java string

Tags: java, jsp, resultset

Here is my data when i view in SQL Developer tool

```
introduction
topic 1

topic end
```

and after i read it using a ResultSet,

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
result.getString("description")
```

and display in JSP page as

```
<bean:write name="data" property="description" />
```

but it will display like this

```
 introduction topic 1 topic end
```

how can i keep the display same as in the SQL Developer?

Comment: Does it look correct if you use "view source" on the HTML page? If so, it's just the browser ignoring line feeds, as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines aren't preserved in HTML.  You need to either tell the browser it's preformatted:

```
<pre>
    <bean:write name="data" property="description"/>
</pre>
```

Or replace the newlines with HTML line breaks.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054/how-can-i-replace-newline-characters-using-jsp-and-jstl) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i keep the display same as in the SQL Developer?

The data presumably contains line breaks, e.g. "\r\n" or "\n". If you look at the *source* of your JSP, you'll probably see them there. However, HTML doesn't treat those as line breaks for *display* purposes - you'll need to either use the `<br />` tag, or put each line in a separate paragraph, or something similar.

Basically, I don't think this is a database problem at all - I think it's an HTML problem. You can experiment with a static HTML file which you edit locally and display in your browser. Once you know the HTML you want to generate, *then* work on integrating it into your JSP.