# Remove newlines and whitespace from jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat

I need to store the html retrieved from a `<jsp:include>` in a javascript variable. So I will have something like this

```
<script>
    var html = '<jsp:include page="...">';
</script>
```

The problem is the jsp file has lots of whitespace and newlines which makes the javascript invalid! I tried using the `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` directive as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208736/1646783), but that **does not remove newlines**.

How can I remove newlines as well from html so it can be a valid javascript string?

Or, another solution is welcome as well.

EDIT:

The snippet should eventually look like this (but with many more options):

```
<script>
    var html = '<label class="someClass">Label</label><select><option value="val1">Value</option></select>';
</script>
```

Comment: what do you expect the snippet you posted to look like after trimming ?

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054/how-can-i-replace-newline-characters-using-jsp-and-jstl

Comment: Not sure how feasible it would be for you, but one way would be to make an AJAX call to run the JSP and get the HTML generated.

Comment: @BheshGurung The AJAX solution will work for now! Thank you. Still curious if there is an alternative/better way.

Comment: To avoid creating newlines, put everything in your included page on one line.

Comment: If your included page contains newlines you're out of luck, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript). So it seems Ajax is the way to go.